# Read numbers from stdin into a Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector Int64

Tags: performance, haskell

Given is a text file (for piping) with many numbers divided by a space, like so:

```
234 456 345 ...
```

What is the best way to read them all into a `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector Int64`? My current code looks like this:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Int
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V

main :: IO ()
main = do
    v <- readInts <$> B.getContents
    print $ V.maximum v

-- splitted for profiling
readInts :: B.ByteString -> V.Vector Int64
readInts = a >>> b >>> c >>> d

a = B.split ' '
b = mapMaybe (B.readInt >>> liftA fst)
c = map fromIntegral
d = V.fromList
```

Here is the profiler output

```
    Thu Sep 18 16:08 2014 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       FastReadInts +RTS -p -K800M -RTS

    total time  =        0.51 secs   (505 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 1,295,988,256 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE  %time %alloc

d           Main     74.3    5.2
b           Main      9.9   35.6
a           Main      6.3   40.0
main        Main      4.8    0.0
c           Main      3.2   19.3


                                                        individual     inherited
COST CENTRE MODULE                    no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN        MAIN                       60           0    0.4    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main       Main                      121           0    4.8    0.0    98.2  100.0
  readInts  Main                      123           0    0.0    0.0    93.5  100.0
   a        Main                      131           0    6.1   40.0     6.1   40.0
   b        Main                      129           0    9.9   35.6     9.9   35.6
   c        Main                      127           0    3.2   19.3     3.2   19.3
   d        Main                      125           0   74.3    5.2    74.3    5.2
 CAF        Main                      119           0    0.0    0.0     0.2    0.0
  a         Main                      130           1    0.2    0.0     0.2    0.0
  b         Main                      128           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  c         Main                      126           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  d         Main                      124           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  readInts  Main                      122           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
  main      Main                      120           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF        GHC.IO.Handle.FD          103           0    0.6    0.0     0.6    0.0
 CAF        GHC.IO.Encoding            96           0    0.2    0.0     0.2    0.0
 CAF        GHC.IO.Handle.Internals    93           0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 CAF        GHC.Conc.Signal            83           0    0.2    0.0     0.2    0.0
 CAF        GHC.IO.Encoding.Iconv      81           0    0.2    0.0     0.2    0.0
```

The programm is compiled and run this way:

```
ghc -O2 -prof -auto-all -rtsopts FastReadInts.hs
./FastReadInts +RTS -p -K800M < many_numbers.txt
```

many_numbers.txt is about 14MB large.

How can this bottleneck, i.e. `V.fromList`, be removed?

Comment: As far as I know, `vector` has very little IO to offer.

Comment: This seems to be very opinion based but if it look to complicated for you then you can always refactore some parts into their own functions (for example splitting/reading into numbers/...) - performancewise I think you are ok (strict-IO check, the other parts should not really hurt performance)

Comment: If you're really worried about performance, you can perform the read inside `IO` and use a mutable vector.  That would get rid of the need to use an intermediate list, but on the whole I would expect the IO to actually be your limiting factor not conversion from a list to a vector.

Comment: @bheklilr: I added some profiling to my post. Surprisingly the conversion from list to vector seems to the be bottleneck.

Comment: @Dobi looking at your code again, I don't know if you'll be able to get around that bottleneck very easily.  The root of the problem is really `B.split`, since it returns a list.  Once you have it as a list, you have to use `V.fromList` to convert to a vector.  Instead, you might be able to get it faster by using a high performance parsing library, but that might be too big a hammer for this nail.

Comment: Do not benchmark with profiling turned on, it slows down things considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to answer questions like this without some expected level of performance or point of comparison.  By simply omitting the profiling your code runs in 100ms over an ASCii file of 21MB of random 64-bit numbers, this seems reasonable to me.

```
$ time ./so < randoms.txt 
9223350746261547498

real    0m0.109s
user    0m0.094s
sys     0m0.013s
```

And the generation of the test data:

```
import System.Random

main = do
    g <- newStdGen
    let rs = take (2^20) $ randomRs (0,2^64) g :: [Integer]
    writeFile "randoms.txt" $ unwords (map show rs)
```

EDIT:

As requested:

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as M
...
listToVector :: [Int64] -> V.Vector Int64
listToVector ls = unsafePerformIO $ do
        m <- M.unsafeNew (2^20)
        zipWithM_ (M.unsafeWrite m) [0..(2^20)-1] ls
        V.unsafeFreeze m
```

Comment: Yes, it is fast, but just out of curiosity I wanted to see if it can improved even more. You pointed out that I have no comparison. That was good, because it made me create one in C++ ( https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/7e75856c149f957bacd4 ). The result is, that even when telling C++ the number of ints in advance (via v.reseve) it is about 300% slower than the Haskell version. I tested with 10000000 numbers. I'm surprised but satisfied. :)

Comment: Similar to in C++ you can pre-allocate a mutable vector of length `2^20`, read in all the data, then perform a no-copy `unsafeFreeze` to obtain your immutable unboxed vector.  This is likely to save you some (though I'd venture to bet not much) for a high cognitive cost.

Comment: See my edit for pre-allocation of vectors.  I'm betting `fromList` is extremely optimized and as such this won't give you much (any?) performance benefit.

Comment: Thank you. I tested `V.fromList` against your `listToVector`. With 10000000 input numbers on my system the version with `V.fromList` needed 2.156s while the one with `listToVector` took 2.319s.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to note that pre-allocating mutable vector does not impact performance too much. In most cases run time will be dominated by reading file.

I have benchmarked both versions on `2^23` numbers and it seems that pre-allocated mutable array is even a bit slower.

```
benchmarking V.fromList
time                 49.51 ms   (47.65 ms .. 51.07 ms)
                     0.998 R²   (0.995 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 48.24 ms   (47.82 ms .. 49.01 ms)
std dev              971.5 μs   (329.1 μs .. 1.438 ms)

benchmarking listToVector
time                 109.9 ms   (106.2 ms .. 119.9 ms)
                     0.993 R²   (0.975 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 109.3 ms   (107.6 ms .. 113.8 ms)
std dev              4.041 ms   (1.149 ms .. 6.129 ms)
```

And here is the code of the benchmark:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad (zipWithM_)
import System.IO.Unsafe
import Data.Int
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as M

import Criterion.Main


main :: IO ()
main = do
  let readInt x = let Just (i,_) = B.readInt x in fromIntegral i
  nums <- map readInt . B.words <$> B.readFile "randoms.txt"

  defaultMain
    [bench "V.fromList"   $ whnf (V.maximum . V.fromList) nums
    ,bench "listToVector" $ whnf (V.maximum . listToVector) nums
    ]

listToVector :: [Int64] -> V.Vector Int64
listToVector ls = unsafePerformIO $ do
    m <- M.unsafeNew (2^23)
    zipWithM_ (M.unsafeWrite m) [0..(2^23)-1] ls
    V.unsafeFreeze m
```